# Provisioning CoreOS with Ansible pip error

Tags: python, pip, ansible, coreos

I am trying to provision a coreOS box using Ansible. First a bootstapped the box using https://github.com/defunctzombie/ansible-coreos-bootstrap

This seems to work ad all but pip (located in /home/core/bin) is not added to the path. In a next step I am trying to run a task that installs docker-py:

```
- name: Install docker-py
  pip: name=docker-py
```

As pip's folder is not in path I did it using ansible:

```
  environment:
    PATH: /home/core/bin:$PATH
```

If I am trying to execute this task I get the following error:

fatal: [192.168.0.160]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "/home/core/bin/pip install docker-py", "failed": true, "msg": "\n:stderr: /home/core/bin/pip: line 2: basename: command not found\n/home/core/bin/pip: line 2: /root/pypy/bin/: No such file or directory\n"}

what I ask is where does `/root/pypy/bin/` come from it seems this is the problem. Any idea?

Comment: Just from looking at the error message, it seems like `basename: command not found` is the root issue that's probably causing the `/root/pypy/bin/` one.

Comment: One interesting fact if I ssh into the box and run `home/core/bin/pip install docker-py` the Command executes without any problems. The failure only occurs if I run it from Ansible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use shell-style variable expansion when setting Ansible variables.  In this statement...

```
environment:
  PATH: /home/core/bin:$PATH
```

...you are setting your `PATH` environment variable to the *literal* value `/home/core/bin:$PATH`.  In other words, you are blowing away any existing value of `$PATH`, which is why you're getting "command not found" errors for basic things like `basename`.

Consider installing `pip` somewhere in your existing `$PATH`, modifying `$PATH` *before* calling ansible, or calling `pip` from a shells cript:

```
- name: install something with pip
  shell: |
    PATH="/home/core/bin:$PATH"
    pip install some_module
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, calling pip using a shell script in ansible creates unfortunately the same error.

Comment: Are you sure you're no longer trying to set PATH in Ansible? Maybe update your question with your new playbook.

Comment: Hey, yes pretty shure, my yml looks as follows: 
`- hosts: rancher-server
  remote_user: coreos
  gather_facts: True
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo

  tasks:
  - name: install something with pip
    shell: |
      PATH="/home/core/bin:$PATH"
      pip install some_module `

Comment: Ok my mistake `- hosts: rancher-server
  remote_user: coreos

  tasks:
  - name: install something with pip
    shell: |
      PATH=/home/core/bin:$PATH
      pip install docker-py` Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in /home/core/bin/pip script which is literally:

```
#!/bin/bash
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/pypy/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH $HOME/pypy/bin/$(basename $0) $@
```

when run under root by ansible the `$HOME` variable is substituted with /root and not with /home/core.
Change `$HOME` with `/home/core` and it should work.